# Polymer Paper Menu not displaying properly over Data Grid / Table

Tags: dart, polymer, slickgrid, dart-polymer, bwu-datagrid

I am showing a paper menu (Dart-Polymer Element) whenever a user clicks a menu button inside of a BWU Datagrid which is a Dart port of SlickGrid. The elements behind the menu still show and the user can actually click items behind the menu.

Here's an image of the problem to give you a better idea:

[image: Image of Menu Elements Seeping Through]

Here's my CSS changes to for the popup menu:

```css
/* dropdown menu */
cr-table /deep/ a {
  width: 40px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  vertical-align: middle;
}    
/** Pretty transition for showing the menu button */
cr-table /deep/ div.bwu-datagrid-row paper-menu-button.menu-button {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s linear 0.3s,opacity 0.3s linear;
}
cr-table /deep/ div.bwu-datagrid-row:HOVER paper-menu-button.menu-button {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

**Note:**

- Keep in mind the table is a Dart Polymer element which uses a BWU-DataGrid.
- The "a" element is the text inside the Product cells.
- CR-Table is just a wrapper for a BWU-DataGrid

Comment: I had a very similar problem with the tooltip element (I created the bwu_datagrid) I think this is some browser bug. I have to look it up how I coped with this...

Comment: Interesting didn't think about trying another browser. Tried regular chrome but the menu didn't show at all. Let me know if you remember how you ended up fixing it. DataGrid is awesome by the way :D

Comment: As far as I remember this has to do with `opacity`. Can you try to remove all opacity settings (and alpha values if you have any)?

Comment: I went ahead and removed all opacity and alpha values. Didn't seem to work. You think it might be the positioning? Since the BWU DataGrid uses absolute position for the cells?

Comment: Have you removed opacity only from the dropdown or also from the grid (rows, cells)? I don't remember what exactly fixed it, I played around several hours and found a way around the problem, but don't remember details besides that I think it had to do with opacity. Dartium and Chromium are mostly the same and have the same bugs. Testing with other browser doesn't tell much either because they have no shadow DOM.

Comment: At least now I know that's it's a CSS issue. I removed opacity from the table and the menu so everything has default values now. I found this article on z-index and positioning, reading through it now.

http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Comment: The info from your link seems to explain a lot ...

Comment: So you were right, it was a CSS issue! Turns out just needed to add a z-index of 2 (greater than 1) on the BWU table cells. Actually increasing the default z-index for the cells. weird.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I've been scratching my head for days. I'll go ahead and leave an answer for anyone who stumbles on this again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the BWU DataGrid's cells z-index to a value greater than 1, but less than the z-index of the actual paper menu (which has a default of 12).

```css
cr-table /deep/ div.bwu-datagrid-cell {
    z-index: 2;
}
```